# Mailpoet and Mandrill plugins: Email issue for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, mandrill

On my current wordpress, I am using Mailpoet plugin for my emails which includes system emails, newsletters etc. And I have setted it as sending with my own server. I have another plugin called Paid Memebership Pro, and its sending emails for the account creation and other more activities under it.

Now, I want to use mandrill for sending out bulk emails to my subscribers, users and new customers. For now, I have created one template in my mandrill. Currently, I have installed wpMandrill plugin which sends emails that are generated by WordPress through Mandrill, a transactional email service powered by MailChimp. It allows me to select only one email template at a time.

Due to this my old MailPoet setting is vanished and all mails are using new wpMandrill plugin which has mandrill server for sending out all email. This plugin use only one template for sending all emails. So my original system email, Paid Memebership Pro emails have been replaced by this new template and creating so much problem.

Looking for the better solution. For now, I have deactivated wpMandrill plugin and all works fine, but, I needed to use mandrill for sending out my emails for upcoming events.

Answer (score 0):

Try Pepipost's (www.pepipost.com) plugin for sending Emails with MailPoet.
Download Pepipost's WordPress Plugin from this Link: 
http://www.pepipost.com/wp-pepipost.zip
Help Doc: http://support.pepipost.com/help_center